# How to Keep the partial view fixed during page refresh in MVC using Angular js

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

In my project whenever the page loads the current value of $scope get lost. So How could I save the value of $scope during page refresh. What I want is whenever the user clicks over "system", finance" or "excise" button and its corresponds partial view loads up but whenever the the page gets refreshed the current value of $scope get lost.

In my layout page I'm displaying the partial views on a button click which was handled by angular code.

Code of angular file:

```
var app = angular.module("AppModule",[]);

app.controller("MainController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.system = false;
    $scope.excise = true;
    $scope.finance = true;

    $scope.menu = function (menuname) {
        debugger;
        if (menuname == '_SystemMenus') {
            $scope.system = false;
            $scope.excise = true;
            $scope.finance = true;
        }

        else if (menuname == '_ExciseMenus') {
            $scope.system = true;
            $scope.excise = false;
            $scope.finance = true;
        }
        else {
            $scope.system = true;
            $scope.excise = true;
            $scope.finance = false;
        }
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$window.localStorage` to store your scope data.

to set:

```
$window.localStorage[key]= value
```

to get:

```
$window.localStorage[key]
```